# Error in Adding onClickListeners to the buttons

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I am writing a simple android program for app, in that there is 2 button , i am just trying click the button & display some msg by clicking ,
here is my code for two buttons .

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);        
    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(startListener); // Register the onClick listener with             the implementation above

    Button buttonStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);        
    buttonStop.setOnClickListener(stopListener); // Register the onClick listener with the implementation above
     }


   //Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener
    private OnClickListener startListener = new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
      Log.d(logtag,"onClick() called - start button");              
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The Start button was clicked.",          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Log.d(logtag,"onClick() ended - start button");
    }
   };

    // Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener
    private OnClickListener stopListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
     Log.d(logtag,"onClick() called - stop button"); 
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The Stop button was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Log.d(logtag,"onClick() ended - stop button");
    } 
    };
```

my error is saying that "OnClickListener cannot be resolved to a type"

can anyone help me in this . .

Comment: use keyboard shortcut :  `Ctrl+Shift+O ` to organize imports and choose the `android.view.View.OnclickListener` from the pop up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "OnClickListener cannot be resolved to a type"

Need to import View.OnclickListener in current Activity :

```
import android.view.View.OnclickListener;
```

Comment: but in suggestion it is not showing import , instead it s saying create class for startListener

Comment: @RaghavendraM : you already implemented `OnClickListener` interface. if still facing issue then use `View.OnclickListener` instead of `OnclickListener` for `stopListener` instance